# MySQL: Ignore row when summing a field if another table contains a certain value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, conditional-statements

I have three tables, one called orders (containing only customer info), another called orders_total (containing order subtotals, discounts, and totals), and the last one called orders_products (containing names and prices of items being ordered). They all tied by a common field called orders_id.

I am trying to aggregate (sum) total sales revenue EXCEPT for orders that contain Item X (from the orders_products table), but for some reason the sum of sales revenues aren't adding up properly when I introduce the third table (orders_products). I know how to do the aggregation and the item exception separately with any two of three tables, but the complexity for me is combining both functions by introducing the third table. Here is my properly working query so far with just the two original tables:

```
SELECT o.orders_id, ot.orders_id, o.delivery_state, SUM(ot.revenue) AS ordersum
FROM orders_total ot, orders o
WHERE ot.orders_id = o.orders_id
GROUP BY o.delivery_state
ORDER BY ordersum DESC;
```

How would I implement the exception to ignore orders that contain Item X?

Comment: How is `orders_products` related to the other two tables?

Comment: orders_products contains info regarding the products the customer ordered, one row per product. Each product row is identified by orders_id to associate with the orders table. The field of interest is 'product_name'. So in this case, I would like to not aggregate totals if the customer's order contains any product_name called 'Item X'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply exclude any orders from your original query which are identified via a subselect:

```
SELECT o.orders_id, ot.orders_id, o.delivery_state, SUM(ot.revenue) AS ordersum
FROM orders_total ot
INNER JOIN orders o ON ot.orders_id = o.orders_id
WHERE ot.orders_id NOT IN (SELECT orders_id FROM orders_products WHERE product_name = '?')
GROUP BY o.delivery_state
ORDER BY ordersum DESC;
```

Note that `?` represents the product_name you are trying to exclude.

You also probably don't want `orders_id` information as part of your select, as that is meaningless data with regards to this aggregation.

For this query to run well make sure you have indexes on:

```
orders_products.product_name
orders.delivery_date
orders.orders_id
orders_total.orders_id
```

Comment: That's what I originally did... The strange thing is I get correct sums when I only deal with orders and orders_totals (for example, orders from the state of Massachusetts would result in $60k total revenue), but when I add the orders_products table using INNER JOIN and subselects... it just gets stuck in loading the php page. Any idea?

Comment: Nevermind. The query does work -- it just loaded EXTREMELY SLOW. I guess it's trying to search the entire orders_products table, which is quite large, for that specific item. How would you suggest I speed the query up?

Comment: @user2337231 Are you getting any errors?  It is possible that you are timing out if you have large datasets and are not using proper indexes.

Comment: @user2337231 See my updated answer for comments on indexes that you need to have in place.

Comment: MySQL is also notoriously bad about optimizing subqueries in general, and `NOT IN` subqueries specifically.

Comment: I see. The only index I have for the orders_products table is order_products_id, which is just a unique id per row. As multiple customers can order the same products, the product_name and product_catno are non-unique. Is there a way I can get order_products_id involved here, or do I have to create non-unique indexes?

Comment: @user2337231 You would need to add a non-unique index on order_products.products_name.  That is ultimately what you are filtering against, so you need to have an index for it.

Answer (score 0):

Join to your main query a subquery that selects the orders that contain item X, and then filter out those that don't in the argument to `SUM()`.

```
SELECT
    o.orders_id,
    ot.orders_id,
    o.delivery_state,
    SUM(CASE WHEN op.orders_id IS NULL THEN ot.revenue ELSE 0 END) AS ordersum

FROM orders_total ot

INNER JOIN orders o
ON ot.orders_id = o.orders_id

LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT orders_id
    FROM orders_products
    WHERE ... -- Add your condition to select only item X
) op
ON op.orders_id = o.orders_id

GROUP BY o.delivery_state

ORDER BY ordersum DESC;
```

Comment: Would you say this is more efficient than the Mike Brant's suggestion without a unique index for the product_name?

Comment: It is likely to be, since it guarantees that the subquery is run exactly once.  The only way to be sure is to try it and see.  And I would still highly recommend adding the index.